# Candidates to merge?

Tags: discussion, questions, merging-questions

There are two very similar questions on defining what project is:

- [Disregard PMBOK. How could I define a Project?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/4190/disregard-pmbok-how-could-i-define-a-project)
- [What is the generally-accepted definition of a "software project?"](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/definition-of-software-project)

Should they be merged?

Answer (score 2):

The only concern I have is one question states to disregard the PMBOK, while the other one has an answer that explicitly quotes the PMBOK.

If we merged them, I guess we could edit the non PMBOK answer to indicate that the poster is answering in the context of specifically *not* referencing the PMBOK, since the other question doesn't state the preference either way. I'd hate to not merge just because of one easily-fixable issue...

Also, if I merged, I'd use Pawel's version of the question as the canonical version. It's better written, has more answers, and has more upvotes.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'd second this approach. Merging them, but highlighting that Pawel's answer sounds more like an 'oficial' definition, while the answers from other topics may be edited to present a 'non oficial' point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Although you ask different questions, the answers of the first question bring any added value compared to the answers in the second question. I would merge them.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are distinct, but that merging them will create a question/answer with more value.